# Reflection emit stack and method call

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

Can someone explain to me what needs to be loaded into the stack prior to making a function call via reflection.emit?

I have a very simple method

```
public static void Execute(string 1, string 2)
```

I want to generate the method in the following class dynamically (forget the rest, I got them sorted out)

```
public class Test{
    public string s1;

    public void Run(string s2)
    {
        MyOtherClass.Execute(s2,s1)
    }
}
```

I have a copy of the above test, for reference, and I noticed the following opcodes were emitted, prior to the "call".

1. ldarg_1
2. ldarg_0
3. ldfld

The question is what's ldarg_0 doing there? I only need 2 arguments for the call, why does the CLR requires ldarg_0 to be pushed to the stack?

Comment: Can you provide the surrounding IL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`arg.0` contains `this` and is required by `ldfld string Test:s1` to push `this.s1` onto the stack.

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Run(string s2) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8                                      // maximum stack size 8
    ldarg.1                                          // push argument s2
    ldarg.0                                          // push this
    ldfld string Test::s1                            // pop this, push this.s1
    call void MyOtherClass::Execute(string, string)  // call
    ret                                              // return
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know what I missed now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push the method's arguments in order of declaration and an object reference if the method is not static. In your test case, you are accessing a member field (`s1`), so you need the `this` reference for it. That's what `ldarg_0` provides. The subsequent `ldfld` pops the `this` reference and pushes the field's value onto the evaluation stack.